# When taking screenshot on Ios website scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I am loading a web application in safari browser, when capture a screeenshot, the view scrolls up. Why is this happening and How can I prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

setting a max-height to the container solved this issue.